# CMake cache windows

Tags: c++, cmake

When using CMake on unix I dont have any issues. I can use CLion to do a cmake setup, cmake build and cmake install, open a different project and it will find the previously built library when using `find_package`. On windows this does not seem to be possible. By default it tries to install the build code into strange directories (like `C:\Program Files`). I have added a `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to both my library `CMakeLists.txt` and the appliation `CMakeLists.txt`, however when using `find_package(SDL2)`CMake still complains there is no config file for CMake and SDL2. When checking the following file exists:

`U:\various\cmake-cache\Program Files (x86)\SDL2\cmake\SDL2Config.cmake`

The directory `U:\various\cmake-cache` was used as CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX for both SDL2 and my application. Yet it still refuses to compile.

What can I do to make CMake at least somewhat useful on windows? On Unix things work great, but it feels like a huge PITA on Windows so far... It seems like all the concepts dont work there. I would really like to have one central location that is used by every CMake build on my system and everything is installed there and when another project uses a library it is searched there. Is this possible?

Comment: ***What can I do to make CMake at least somewhat useful on windows?*** I use environment variables. And always run CMake-gui from a command window with these environment variables set. Different compiler versions have totally different environment variable sets. I have a separate build tree for these. And a shortcut in the root folder of the tree that automatically opens a cmd window with the environment variables set for that tree. This is how I have done this for the decade+ that I have used CMake under windows.

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` affects only on file installed by your project, it doesn't help to find things. Instead, set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable to `U:\various\cmake-cache\Program Files (x86)`.